# How to use getPageSource method while page contains 2 texts and same starting 3 charactres (ex : Ski, Ski Boot)?

Tags: java, selenium

I used getPageSource() method to find text in a page but the problem is, if the page contains like Ski and Ski Boots. I need to find Ski but it returns with Ski Boot. Can I use getPageSource.equal("Ski") method instead of using getPageSource.contains("Ski")?

Answer (score 0):

`equals()` : method would compare two strings, and would return *true* if the strings are equal, *false* if not.

So *`getPageSource.equal("Ski")`* will return **true** / **false** incase of exact match.

*`contains()`* : method checks whether the string contains a sequence of characters. This method returns *true* if the characters exist and *false* if not.

So *`getPageSource.contains("Ski")`* will return **true** / **false** incase of partial match.

As **`Ski`** is present in both `Ski` and `Ski Boots` hence you there are two matches.

Comment: Actually, I have to use switch case for this, I mean if the page contains "Ski" means it enters some value in text box if the page contains "Ski Boots" means it returns some value to text box now I have problem like if "Ski Boots" is displayed in the screen means it returns both the value of "Ski" and "Ski Boots". How to find exact value that returns only "Ski Boots" value to the text box. Thanks